# Dreamweaver CS5 Live View Not Working

Tags: dreamweaver

The Live View in Dreamweaver (CS5) stopped working for me. The basic background and whatnot shows up in the design view, but switching to live view just discards all of the CSS. I've tried all the basics (quitting, refreshing, loading a different project), but nothing's working. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks~B

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Troubleshoot section on the [Dreamweaver / Viewing live data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-79b8a.html) article

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the info didn't help. I think this might have been a blessing in disguise. Dreamweaver, although its relative simplicity has helped get more comfortable with various aspects of web design/development, has to be one of the most uninspiring IDEs out there (IMO). It's like working in the nurse's office in elementary school. There are enough good free/open source options out there that it's worth getting my hands a bit dirty and figure out some different workflows. Particularly, since I'd been using so many tools outside of Dreamweaver for a while now anyway

Comment: PS - No offense or intention to discourage people from using Dreamweaver. The comment above, as stated, is just my opinion. ~B